# Running totals Python: "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"

Tags: python, indentation, cumulative-sum

I get this error when running the code and have no idea why my running total wouldn't work if everything seems indented correctly. This is the error I am getting:

```
totalRooms += rooms
                  ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Here is my program:

```
def main():

    developerInfo()

    totalFloors = int(input('Enter the number of floors in the hotel: '))
    totalRoomsOccupied = 0
    totalRoomsUnoccupied = 0
    totalRooms = 0



    for hotelRateLoop in range(totalFloors):


        rooms = int(input('Enter the number of rooms on the floor: '))
        roomsOccupied = int(input('Enter the number of rooms occupied: '))
        roomsUnoccupied = int(rooms - roomsOccupied)


        totalRooms += rooms
        totalRoomsOccupied += roomsOccupied
        totalRoomsUnoccupied += roomsUnoccupied

    occupancyRate = float(totalRoomsOccupied / totalRooms)

    print('Total number of rooms: ' + str(totalRooms))
    print('Total number of rooms occupied: ' + str(totalRoomsOccupied))
    print('Total number of rooms unoccupied: ' + str(totalRoomsUnoccupied))
    print('Occupancy Rate: ' + format((occupancyRate * 100), '.2f') + '%')
```

Comment: you may have mixed tabs and spaces in your code. Either use spaces or tabs for indentations. If you are using specific tools like `sublime` or `pycharm` there's an option to convert tabs into spaces and vice versa.

Comment: Have you copied the code from somewhere?

Comment: I am using sublime and checked to see if I mixed the tabs and spaces...you were right!! Thank you so much!!!